# Mount merged partition at boot, fuse module missing

Tags: fstab, fuse, modprobe, alpine

I have a merged partition from 3 different hard drives with [mergerfs](https://github.com/trapexit/mergerfs). I set it up following [this tutorial](https://www.teknophiles.com/2018/02/19/disk-pooling-in-linux-with-mergerfs/).

To automate the mounting I added instructions in the `fstab` :

```
UUID=b3c8301c-5d12-4ab1-ab8c-9249e81978df   /   ext4    rw,relatime,data=ordered 0 1
UUID=f510cf24-8253-4178-99dd-a23a02e912c1   /boot   ext4    rw,relatime,data=ordered 0 2
UUID=9a586ac1-ba39-4004-8ed8-3a6956ae23e7   swap    swap    defaults    0 0
UUID=a3f39fe8-0917-4990-9264-8814a7d0a3b3   /mnt/data_01    ext4    defaults 0 2
UUID=1c78e917-e81c-4719-aecd-211326a579aa   /mnt/data_02    ext4    defaults 0 2
UUID=ac5599bf-0c3b-4785-bc3d-a0cddd32fe28   /mnt/data_03    ext4    defaults 0 2
/mnt/data_* /mnt/data   fuse.mergerfs   defaults,allow_other,use_ino,fsname=data_merger 0 0
```

When I do `mount -a` the first time it fail with this message : `fuse: device not found, try 'modprobe fuse' first`. So I do it and the second `mount -a` works perfectly. After this, the merged partition behave as expected.

But when I reboot, the partition is not mounted. I assumed that is because `modprobe fuse` is not run before the `fstab` process. I don't know how to manage it, I read that rebuild the kernel with `fuse` could be a solution, but it seems a bit overkill.

Any idea?

Comment: if it is Ubuntu(It should depend on grub but double check) use `insmod fuse` in /boot/grub/grub.cfg. Issue is you have to call module before mounting file system.

Comment: It's Alpine Linux, I will check if it's possible here too.

Comment: @asktyagi I don't have grub in Alpine

Comment: Please check `append` option in syslinux, if that having any option to load kernel. Else you have to take different way to fix.

Comment: @asktyagi I don't see any `append` option when I run `syslinux --help`

Comment: I am not familier with alpine however please check this option https://wiki.syslinux.org/wiki/index.php?title=Config#PATH according to doc you can load your module with path.

Comment: @asktyagi I added my Syslinux file to the question. So do you suggest me to add `fuse` in `PATH`? Is it not going to be override at every kernel update? I'm also afraid to block my server boot if I mess with this file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a simple an elegant solution : register `fuse` in `/etc/modules`. Adding this one in this file do the trick since they are loaded before `fstab`.